# WordPress Child Theme Not Functioning Properly on Ubuntu

Tags: css, linux, wordpress, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am a bit new at this, so forgive me if I don't explain properly, but I'll do my best.

So, I am a fresh developer of sorts.  Everyone in my section of the office uses a Macbook Pro.  Upon hiring, some confusion on my part led me to get a Windows laptop, as I thought was the standard at my office.  I take that back, one very talented co-worker also uses a Windows PC.

When my superiors were baffled that I chose the Windows computer that they offered me, I felt defeated, but, alas, Linux to the rescue.  My fellow Windows user said he preferred running Linux on Ubuntu through a VM on the PC as the specs on were equal and likely better than the Macbook that our company offered.

So, he help me set up Ubuntu on this solid state Dell PC, and everything has been just fine.  Well, for the most part everything has been fine.  Ubuntu isn't much different than the Mac OS, but things such as permissions (and actually using the terminal--took me a while to figure that out) are a little different.

So, that's the back story.  My partner on this project is using the most current Mac OS X, and I'm using the most current version of Ubuntu.  He is working on a client's WordPress site.  It uses a parent and child theme.  It's working just fine on his machine.

He gave the entire project file to me, database included, via external HD.  Well, we instantly had problems.  We had to re-setup some of the plugins and add-on files (to be expected).  But then the site itself on my localhost just wouldn't work.

So we looked and looked and looked and determined that the child theme could not find a folder in the parent theme, so we copied that file over to the child theme.  Voila, it kind of worked.  But even in my limited experience I know that defeats the purpose of parent/child structure and is just a bad idea.  But even then the CSS wasn't coming over along with imported fonts and images and whatnot.

Basically, the child theme is only reading some of the parent them, if any.  The basic structured of the website and WordPress is up and running, but the styles just aren't coming over.  It's looking in the child theme (as we discovered in the console), but it should be looking in the parent--which it does on his machine but not mine.

So, we put link files/folders in the child as a temporary patch, but still some files and styles aren't coming through.

I cannot exchange laptops, so I'm stuck running Ubuntu, which I thought would be fine.  But it seems that my machine is just not reading these files the same as his despite our files being exactly the same initially.

I've edited permissions as best as I could, too, so I don't *think* that's an issue, but it might be.

As an Ubuntu and programming newbie, I appreciate any help.  I know this was more than a narrative than a specific question, but honestly I'm struggling to know the specific problem.  I'll respond to any questions as best as I can.

Thanks guys and gals.

EDIT: WP Debug info:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/mu-plugins/ubermenu/core/UberMenu.class.php on line 937

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/mu-plugins/ubermenu/core/UberMenu.class.php on line 937

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/mu-plugins/ubermenu/core/UberMenu.class.php on line 937

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/mu-plugins/ubermenu/core/UberMenu.class.php on line 937

Notice: Use of undefined constant TABBER_TABS_DIR - assumed 'TABBER_TABS_DIR' in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/mu-plugins/tabber-tabs/tabber-tabs.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: tabber_tabs in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/mu-plugins/tabber-tabs/tabber-tabs.php on line 125

Notice: Undefined index: csmt_taxonomies in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/plugins/category-seo-meta-tags/category-seo-meta-tags.php on line 102

Notice: Use of undefined constant show_category_title - assumed 'show_category_title' in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/plugins/category-seo-meta-tags/category-seo-meta-tags.php on line 532

Notice: Use of undefined constant show_tag_title - assumed 'show_tag_title' in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/plugins/category-seo-meta-tags/category-seo-meta-tags.php on line 533

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2959

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 77 of 1273 bytes in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/lib/plugin/Ai1ecFacebookConnectorPlugin.php on line 726

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 77 of 1273 bytes in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/lib/plugin/Ai1ecFacebookConnectorPlugin.php on line 726

Comment: Does TwentyTwelve works? What if you do a child theme for it? Have you enabled WP_DEBUG?

Comment: I did turn on WP_DEBUG, but all it really told me is what files were not loading correctly. Thank you for your response!

Comment: You have to add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question, without that it's just a description of a strange problem, and unless someone who already had the same problem read this, it'll be difficult to offer any assistance.

Comment: I gotcha.  Just added.  My mistake.

Comment: Can't you format this? See http://sscce.org

Comment: To some extent.  I'll format how I know how.  After that, I'm pretty new at this, so what you see is what you get, haha.

Comment: What `tabber-tabs` and `ubermenu` are doing inside `/wp-content/mu-plugins`? Maybe it's unrelated, but it's totally weird. Rename the folder to `mu-plugins-bak` and see what happens.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function dynamic_sidebar_from_blog() in /home/cstone/dev/thesite/wp-content/themes/akita-child/header.php on line 140 Warning: Unknown: 1 result set(s) not freed. Use mysql_free_result to free result sets which were requested using mysql_query() in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Looks like this needs hand-on involvement. My last suggestion, start from scratch. See how a brand new installation works in your machine, so you can rule out misconfigurations in your localhost. Moving a WP site from one machine/server/domain to another uses to be very easy, **unless** you have badly coded themes/plugins/functions.